# Overriding "Edited" in window title for NSDocument

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, nswindow, nsdocument, nswindowcontroller

How do I prevent a window title from displaying "Edited" for an NSDocument which is dirty?

I'm managing saving and autosaving myself, using a web service, and just don't want the distraction in the title bar.

I've tried overriding:

- NSDocument's `-isDocumentEdited` and `-hasUnautosavedChanges` always to return `NO`.
- `-[NSWindowController setDocumentEdited]` to do nothing, or always to use `NO` regardless of the parameter's actual value.
- `-[NSWindowController synchronizeWindowTitleWithDocumentName]` to do nothing.
- `-[NSWindow setDocumentEdited]` to do nothing, or always to use `NO` regardless of the parameter's actual value.

In all cases, the title bar still changes to Edited when I make changes to a saved document.

If I override `-[NSDocument updateChangeCount:]` and `-[NSDocument updateChangeCountWithToken:forSaveOperation:]` to do nothing, I can prevent this from happening, but it affects saving, autosaving, and other document behaviors, too.

I also tried this:

```
[[self.window standardWindowButton: NSWindowDocumentVersionsButton] setTitle:nil];
```

That displayed a blank string instead of Edited, but the dash still appeared – the one which normally separates the document name and Edited.

Any idea how to pry apart this part of the window from the document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several options:

1. To get a pointer to the "dash", look for a TextField in [window.contentView.superview.subviews] with a stringValue equals to "-". You can set its text to an empty string as well.

   ```
   @implementation NSWindow (DashRetrivalMethod)
   - (NSTextField*)versionsDashTextField
   {
       NSTextField* res = nil;
       NSView* themeFrame = [self.contentView superview];
       for (NSView* tmp in [themeFrame subviews])
       {
           if ([tmp isKindOfClass:[NSTextField class]])
           {
               if ([[(NSTextField*)tmp stringValue] isEqualToString:@"—"])
               {
                     res = (NSTextField*)tmp;
                     break;
               }
           }
       }
       return res;
   }
   @end
   ```
2. You can override NSWindow's -setRepresentedURL:. This would also affect the NSWindowDocumentIconButton and the popup menu, but you can manually create it if you want by: [NSWindow standardWindowButton: NSWindowDocumentIconButton].
3. Override one of these three NSDocument's undocumented methods:

   ```
   // Always return here NO if you don't want the version button to appear. 
   // This seems to be the cleanest options, besides the fact that you are 
   /// overriding a private method.
   - (BOOL)_shouldShowAutosaveButtonForWindow:(NSWindow*)window;

   // Call super with NO
   - (void)_setShowAutosaveButton:(BOOL)flag; 

   // Here the button and the dash are actually created
   - (void)_endVersionsButtonUpdates; 

   // Here Cocoa hide or unhide the edited button
   - (void)_updateDocumentEditedAndAnimate:(BOOL)flag
   ```

Comment: Excellent solution. @noa you should accept this one. Its awesome. Btw Ben-Uri, by override you mean swizzle right?

Comment: Thanks. No swizzle. Just implement them in your NSDocument subclass as suggested in the comment above each method prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried overriding NSDocuments `- (BOOL)hasUnautosavedChanges` in addition to overriding `- (BOOL) isDocumentEdited`?

Comment: It's a good thought. After autosaving, though, Edited appears until the user explicitly initiates a Save operation, by Apple's design. That said, I tested it anyway: having both `-hasUnautosavedChanges`  and `-isDocumentEdited` return NO, Edited appeared anyway.

Comment: Ok, this was my only idea unfortunately. I assume that dropping NSDocument as basis for the application, and only using NSDocumentController, would require a major rewrite of your application?

Comment: That's right. Reimplementing `-updateChangeCount:`, `-updateChangeCountForToken:forSaveOperation:`, `-isDocumentEdited` and `-hasUnautosavedChanges` might be feasible, but even that seems drastic, and potentially difficult to maintain. Not telling the document about its window is another possibility, but again, drastic.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a late answer, you can easily determine what is going to be the title of your NSDocument window by overriding

```
- (NSString *)windowTitleForDocumentDisplayName:(NSString *)displayName
```

in your NSWindowController and return the appropriate title.

You can do that also by overriding the property of your NSDocument:

```
- (NSString *)displayName
```

but this is **not** recommended by Apple, because that is normally used by the OS error handlers.

I added this answer, because none of the other answers really set me on the right path.